# How to load the Wordpress environment in a php script?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

How can I load the Wordpress environment in a script, so I can use Wordpress' functions?

I need this because I need to call several functions from a script which is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to load the wp-load.php file, which will then allow you to call wordpress functions.

For example:

```
require( '../wordpress/wp-load.php' );
```

with 'wordpress' being your install root.

Comment: you can then use get_header() and get_footer() to append your themes header and footer to your app

Comment: If you only want some Wordpress basics, like config options you can use the following before including wp-load.php: `define("SHORTINIT", 1);`

Comment: This is a little something that I use to take care of relative WordPress installation paths: `$wp_path = explode('wp-content', dirname(__FILE__)); require($wp_path[0].'wp-load.php'); `